# How to use SkeletonView besides UITableView/UICollectionView RxCocoa binding

Tags: ios, rx-swift, rx-cocoa, skeleton-ui

For using [SkeletonView](https://github.com/Juanpe/SkeletonView) you have to implement `UITableView/UICollectionView dataSource` which i can't use beacuse i'm using `tableView.rx.items` to bind my table to some observable. so how can i use `RxCocoa` besides `SkeletonView`.

any suggestion?

For more info: `RxSkeleton` library is not good idea for a non-RxDataSourced tableView

Answer (score 1):

You can always create your own data source. Just write a class that conforms to both  `SkeletonTableViewDataSource` and `RxTableViewDataSourceType` then you can pass an instance into `items`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can you please give a complete example code on a repo or here? @Daniel T.

Comment: No I can't. I've never used `SkeletonTableView`. However, if you create your own type and have it conform to the above two protocols, the compiler will tell you what functions to put it in.